# Most moves by Most number of Pieces

Tags: mathematics, chess, optimization, checkerboard

Using one color, White or Black, place as many chess pieces (kings, queens, bishops, knights, rooks, and pawns, or combinations thereof) as you can on a checkerboard so that when the number of pieces is multiplied by the number of the possible moves, we get the greatest value S , where S = (no.of pieces) X (no. of moves). Without having the pieces attacking each other, what is the greatest value possible?

Comment: Does "without attacking" mean "without threatening" (which would limit the number of pieces) or do just mean without counting attacking moves?

Comment: @Daniel Mathias-It seems that my answer to your comment on had never added. That is,  without attacking or capturing or threatening of other pieces . Thus Qs cannot be side by side

Comment: Answer updated accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> 32 knights and the number of possible moves for each:
>  N . N . N . N .   2 . 4 . 4 . 3 .  =13
>  . N . N . N . N   . 4 . 6 . 6 . 3  +19=32
>  N . N . N . N .   4 . 8 . 8 . 6 .  +26=58
>  . N . N . N . N   . 6 . 8 . 8 . 4  +26=84
>  N . N . N . N .   4 . 8 . 8 . 6 .  +26=110
>  . N . N . N . N   . 6 . 8 . 8 . 4  +26=136
>  N . N . N . N .   3 . 6 . 6 . 4 .  +19=155
>  . N . N . N . N   . 3 . 4 . 4 . 2  +13=168
>  32*168=5376
> ```